# Why are C++ (Visual Studio) Datatypes not stopping on their Limit?

Tags: c++, types

Usually, it would be more secure and better (to avoid UB for example) if Datatypes stop working (program crashes or whatever) instead of having no kind of information if their limit is exceeded.

For example, the limit of `unsigned char` is **255**, now let's say the value 3000 is stored as unsigned char in a text-file, and loaded into the C++ program. It will not give any error or something, instead `unsigned char` will just do some auto-conversion (or UB?) and give some another value, below it's limit. But why? What is that good for?

**Is there any way, to make programs build with Visual Studio stop working (crashing or give an alert etc.) if the data type which is used to handle the value is exceeded?**

Same with signed/unsigned data types, if you use unsigned, but you load "-1" value somehow, the unsigned data type is just "accepting" it but gives you some other value above 0.

Comment: Please distinguish between Visual Studio - which is an IDE - from the language - which in your case appears to be C++.

Comment: Out of curiosity: How do you store the value 3000 as unsigned char in a text-file? That seems impossible to me... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important reason for the missing checks is in most cases performance. C++ follows the principle Don't get what you don't buy. If you need checks, write a custom type which makes the check. You can even let it to do the checks in debug mode only. (E.g. `std::vector` does it in its `operator[]`.) If you want a safe language C++ is your worst choice (right after C and assembly). ;-) But there are many other higher level languages you can choose from.

For debug checks, there is a macro in the standard library: [**`assert()`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert):

```c
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define assert(condition) ((void)0)
#else
#define assert(condition) /*implementation defined*/
#endif
```

Thereby, the `/*implementation defined*/` part checks the `condition`. If it results to `false` then usually [**`abort()`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort) is called which in turn aborts the process immediately (usually producing a core dump which can be evaluated in a debugger).

> **Is there any way, to make programs build with Visual Studio stop working (crashing or give an alert etc.) if the data type which is used to handle the value is exceeded?**
>
> Same with signed/unsigned data types, if you use unsigned, but you load "-1" value somehow, the unsigned data type is just "accepting" it but gives you some other value above 0.

Yes, there is a way – using custom types as wrappers around the originals.

A simple sample to demonstrate this:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

struct UChar {
  unsigned char value;

  UChar(unsigned char value = 0): value(value) { }
  UChar(char value): value((assert(value >= 0), (unsigned char)value)) { }
  UChar(int value): value((assert(value >= 0 && value < 256), value)) { }
  UChar(unsigned value): value((assert(value < 256), value)) { }
  UChar(long value): value((assert(value >= 0 && value < 256), value)) { }
  UChar(unsigned long value): value((assert(value < 256), value)) { }
  UChar(long long value): value((assert(value >= 0 && value < 256), value)) { }
  UChar(unsigned long long value): value((assert(value < 256), value)) { }
  UChar(const UChar&) = default;
  UChar& operator=(const UChar&) = default;
  ~UChar() = default;

  operator unsigned char() { return value; }
};

#define PRINT_AND_DO(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  // OK
  PRINT_AND_DO(UChar c);
  PRINT_AND_DO(std::cout << "c: " << (unsigned)c << '\n');
  PRINT_AND_DO(c = 'A');
  PRINT_AND_DO(std::cout << "c: " << c << '\n');
  PRINT_AND_DO(UChar d = 'B');
  PRINT_AND_DO(std::cout << "d: " << d << '\n');
  PRINT_AND_DO(d = c);
  PRINT_AND_DO(std::cout << "d: " << d << '\n');
  // This will crash if NDEBUG not defined:
  //PRINT_AND_DO(UChar e(3000));
  //PRINT_AND_DO(c = 3000);
  PRINT_AND_DO(d = -1);
}
```

Output:

```
a.out: main.cpp:9: UChar::UChar(int): Assertion `value >= 0 && value < 256' failed.
UChar c;
std::cout << "c: " << (unsigned)c << '\n';
c: 0
c = 'A';
std::cout << "c: " << c << '\n';
c: A
UChar d = 'B';
std::cout << "d: " << d << '\n';
d: B
d = c;
std::cout << "d: " << d << '\n';
d: A
d = -1;
bash: line 7: 31094 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4932bc3722fa2631)

**Note:**

This is a demonstration only – not production ready code. E.g. overflow in addition or underflow in subtraction is not catched because the conversion operator `operator unsigned char()` causes the wrapper instance is converted back to `unsigned char` whenever an operator is used which is not overloaded in `struct UChar` (but supports `unsigned char`). To fix this, more operators have to be overloaded for `UChar`. However, I believe the demo is good enough to show the principle.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not managed by C++ (as you've seen). It is called a wrap-around. I.e. the number is truncated to whatever value the variable can hold as if it was wrapping back to zero once its "limit" is exceeded. (for positive numbers at least).

The reason this is not caught is that it can be useful to have this feature.

**That being said** - The compiler should give you a warning though if you assign a constant number that is too large for the variable, or if you assign a "bigger-container" type into a smaller one (like uint16 into uint8).
You can configure the compiler to fail compilation on these kinds of warnings and so you would have ot explicitely convert types.

Answer (score 0):

A programming language, particularly one as close to hardware as C/C++ are, generally only exposes what a typical microprocessor provides in its instruction set. Taking x86 as an example, when you add to integers - typically - the processor will set the OV flag if an overflow happened and IIRC OV and SIGN flags for underflows.

Normally, the compilers do not generate extra instructions to check for these flags after every arithmetic operation which could under-/over-flow. That costs performance, and performance is king, even over correctness, it seems.

The concept you are looking for is two-fold:

- Saturating arithmetic: Where no matter what you do, a variable is clipped to min/max of its datatype's range. No exceptions are raised.
- Compiler explicitly checks for under-/over-flows: The closest example I can think of is [checked { }](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) construct in C#, which you should note is not enabled by default.

P.S.: I also recall that x86 might have added saturating arithmetic in its instruction set at some point, perhaps through the SIMD extensions.